# Components of Graph of $H_n$

Tags: graph-theory

For each $n>=1$ define the following graph $H_n$: The vertices of $H_n$ are $n$-tuples whose
entries are either $0$ or $1$. Two vertices are adjacent if and only of they differ on exactly two coordinates.

How many components does $H_n$ have for each $n>=1$?

I have drawn the graph of $H_2$ and $H_3$ and saw that $H_2$ consists of $2$ straight lines and thus $2$ components and in $H_3$ I saw it consists of $2$ disjoint quadrilaterals and thus $2$ components but for $H_4$ it will consists of more that $2$ components that I found out but I am not getting how to determine it for all $n$.

Comment: Double check your drawing of $H_4$. Hint: find which vertices are in the same component as the all zero $n$-tuple. Note that by symmetry of the graph, each of the components must have equal size, so finding the size of the component with the all zero tuple will tell you the number of components.

Comment: I can divide all the vertices in two sets,one having the sum as even and the other odd,no vertices of the set 1 is connected to a vertex of set 2.Now the vertices (0,1,0,1) and (1,0,1,0) are not connected so they are in different components.so I get more than two components.

Comment: In a component all vertices must me connected.....

Comment: @jyotiprokashroy the vertices $(0,1,0,1)$ and $(1,0,1,0)$ are not directly connected, but they are both connected to $(1,0,0,1)$, so in total, you will end up with two connected components

Comment: yes got it but how do I show that all the vertices having sum even are connected for the n th case.....

Answer (score 2):

Two vertices with an even number of ones differ in an even number of coordinates. Go through these coordinates in pairs, changing the coordinates two at a time. Each of these steps corresponds to traveling along an edge of the graph, and together these edges form a path between the two vertices.

The same argument works for two vertices with an odd number of ones, so these are also connected.

By contrast, an odd vertex and an even vertex differ in an odd number of coordinates. As travelling an edge changes two coordinates, they can never be converted into each other by traveling along edges of the graph; hence they lie in different components.

It follows that the graph has exactly two connected components.