# How to find an Eulerian circuit in a complicated Graph

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

> Consider the following graph G:

[image]

> (a) Give a decomposition of G into cycles.
>
> (b) Find an Eulerian circuit in G.

This is a very complicated graph and each time I am trying to find the solution I am getting lost in the middle. Is there any technique to solve such a problem?
Its really very difficult to find the [Eulerian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path).

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just begin drawing the line with a color pen...

Comment: I know that but getting lost in the middle.Is there any other way?

Comment: how do you get lost? maybe make a bigger drawing

Comment: I did it,thanks

Comment: Can you please clear my doubt in this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440803/components-of-graph-of-h-n

Answer (score 5):

If a Eulerian circut exists, then you can start in any node and color any edge leaving it, then move to the node on the other side of the edge.

Upon arriving at a new node, color any other edge leaving the new node, and move along it.

Repeat the process until you

1. Are forced back to the starting node without covering all edges. In that case, you can expand your cycle because one of your nodes still has two outgoing edges. You can find an euler cycle on the unwalked edges starting and ending on that node.
2. You found an Euler cycle, in which case you are finished.

Comment: Every graph in which all vertices have even degree is Eulerian. The procedure described in this answer is essentially a proof of that fact.

Comment: @AustinMohr false. Every finite connected graph in which all vertices have even degree is.

Answer (score 1):

There are 8 vertices inside and 8 outside. Draw the 8 point star at the center first. Then go out and complete the octagon edges. Then zigzag in and out to finish the remaining edges.

Comment: The OP is not asking how to draw the graph. Please reread his question.

Comment: In a way, OP *is* asking how to draw the graph in such a way that they do not have to lift their pencil and will start and end at the same vertex.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked years ago, but I just came across it, while studying the subject:

(a) Give a decomposition of G into cycles.

Red Cycle: 
9 - 12 - 15 - 10 - 13 - 16 - 11 - 14 - 9

Blue Cycle:
1 - 10 - 3 - 2 - 9 - 8 - 1

Green Cycle:
7 - 14 - 5 - 4 - 13 - 6 - 7

Pink Cycle:
1 - 2 - 11 - 4 - 3 - 12 - 5 - 6 - 15 - 8 - 7 - 16 - 1

(b) Find an Eulerian circuit in G.

1 - 10 - 3 - 2 - 9 - 12 - 15 - 10 - 13 - 16 - 11 - 14 - 9 - 8 - 1 - 2 - 11 - 4 - 3 - 12 - 5 - 6 - 15 - 8 - 7 - 14 - 5 - 4 - 13 - 6 - 7 - 16 - 1

It works!

(Reference https://math.unm.edu/~loring/links/discrete_f05/euler.pdf)[image: Solution]